# Extracting protobuf files/protocols from an APK

Tags: android, reverse-engineering

I've been trying to reverse-engineer an Android API blah blah blah, and I'm trying to extract the protobuf files for it, however I can't find any references of it in the decompiled code or resources outside of Firebase/Google stuff.

I know that they use it, as I can use protoc --decode_raw to see the values, and it's in the response headers.

Likewise, I've tried using [PBTK](https://github.com/marin-m/pbtk), however on Windows it seems to be flawed.

Comment: There's unlikely to be protobuf files in the apk.  Generally those are compiled into Kotlin or Java code at compile time, not read and interpreted at runtime.